# Drupal theme function is not called?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I am new to Drupal and trying to create a theme function that create a little iframe for my videos. I am calling the function in my menu callback function. The problem is that the theme function is not called. I tried to append the module name at the beginning of the theme function and also removed and it didn't help. I clear the cache every time I make changes and enabled the backtrace in my devel module and I see the following warning:

> warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'mymodule_mobile_mymodue_mobile_build_iframe' not
>   found or invalid function name in call_user_func_array() (line 656 of
>   /var/www/includes/theme.inc). =>

```
function my_callback_function(){
$output = theme('mymodule_mobile_build_iframe',array(
           'arg1'=> $stream,
           'arg2'=> $node->nid,)
               );
return $output

}
function mymodule_mobile_theme(){

      return array(
        'mymodule_mobile_build_iframe' => array(
        'arguments'    => array(
        'arg1'    => NULL,
        'arg2'   => NULL,),),);
}

function theme_mymodule_mobile_build_iframe($arg1,$arg2){

    $host = 'http://www.myhost.com';

    $output = '<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls"> <source src=
        "'.$host.'/'.$arg1.'/'.$arg2.'/playlist.m3u8" type="video/mp4" />
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
        </video>';

    return $output;
}
```

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect this is a simple naming problem; is your module called `mymodule` or `mymodule_mobile`? This will be the same name as your module's `.info` file (obviously minus the `.info`).

If it's called `mymodule` then you just need to change your theme hook to be named `mymodule_theme()`. All Drupal hooks are MODULENAME_HOOKNAME(), if your module is called `mymodule` Drupal will be expecting to look for a theme hook function called `mymodule_theme()`.

The simplest test is to put the line `drupal_set_message('test');` as the first line of your theme hook function and clear your caches. If you don't see the `test` message output to the screen, your hook function hasn't run, and it isn't named correctly.

If you do see the `test` message and it still doesn't work I'd suggest it indicates a problem somewhere else, the rest of your code looks spot on.

**EDIT**
I just noticed in a comment you're using a template file...I think there's some confusion as to do so you'd need to have the `template` key in the array returned from `hook_theme()`. Could you just clarify that?

Comment: I have actually tested to see if the hook_theme() is called or not by echoing a string. My module is called mymodule_mobile. The probelem is that theme_mymodule_mobile_build_iframe is not being called. Also, I have tried the template key in my hook_theme as well. I am using the "mobile tools" that switches the theme according to the mobile device size. In this case I set my user agent to iPhone, therefore, the system switches the theme from theme1 to theme2. Could that be the source of the problem?

Comment: Hang on is this Drupal 7? If so your theme function should have the `variables` key instead of the `arguments` key. If it's Drupal 6 then you're passing the arguments to the theme incorrectly in `my_callback_function()`. If it's Drupal 7, without one of `variables` or `render element` in your hook array the theme registry will ignore that entry, and won't register the theme function. And I think that would pretty much cause the problem you're having!!

Comment: I am using Drupal 6. However, I can't pin point the problem in my_callback_fucntion().

Answer (score 0):

i don't see any problem in ur code (i didn't test it) ,  but are you sure you have cleared the cache...please clear the cache and tell me if this problem is still exist

Comment: yes I have cleared the cache and in fact I have checked it to be automatic in the devel module. I have to mention that I am using a template file that only has print $content in there, there are no conditionals or anything. How come it says the function is not found?